# Is there a symbol or representation for tolyl groups as there is for the phenyl group?

Tags: aromatic-compounds, notation

Is there a symbol or representation for tolyl groups as there is for the phenyl group?

Phenyl group is often represented by "Ph" when for a matter of space you can not draw the entire benzene group. Is there any accepted or extended representation for a tolyl group?

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is Tol if I presume you refer to *p*-tolyl.  See for instance page 16 of the [author guidelines](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/page/book/10.1002/047084289x/homepage/forauthors.html) (revision December 2014) of the [Encyclopedia of Organic Reagents](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/047084289X) initiated by Leo Paquette.

On occasion *o*-Tol about the *ortho* isomer, for instance $\ce{P(o-tol)3}$ for [tris(*o*-tolyl)phosphine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tris(o-tolyl)phosphine)  ligand (or as $\ce{P(o-Tol)3}$), too) though this arguably appears more often in figure / table captions to shorten line formulae, than in structure formulae.  And $\ce{P(m-Tol)3}$ as an example with the *meta* isomer.  However outside catalysis I wouldn't consider them as usual as (Ph, Bn, Bz; Tf, Ts, TsO, etc.)

[image]

(Clayden, Greeves, Warren *Organic Chemistry*, Oxford University press, 2nd edition 2012, ISBN 978-0-19-927029-3, p. 1080).

Answer (score 3):

Use tol as abbreviation for tolyl group.

**Ref.**: https://www.axeleratio.com/ip/ligands/abbrev/IndexGrpLigAbbrev.htm